# Computer freezes, makes buzzing noise on speakers

Tags: windows-7, freeze, speakers

My computer has recently been freezing up occasionally (once every one or two days).

When the computer freezes I have been playing a game (League of Legends or Hearthstone) or watching a movie using VLC media player.

This is what happens:

1. Computer freezes.
2. Last played noise going to speakers (extremely short part of audio, only recognizable by tone) repeats itself rapidly for 1 second or so.
3. Sound stops.
4. Computer remains unresponsive to ANYTHING.
5. I am forced to press the power button or reset button.

Things I have tried so far:

1. CMD > chkdsk /r.
2. Windows Memory Diagnostics Tool.
3. Monitored temperatures (they are fine).
4. Looked for Windows Memory.dmp in the location it should be.
5. Checked all connections to everything inside computer.
6. Removed all audio driver applications.
7. Update all drivers

Things I plan to do eventually as I troubleshoot:

1. Place RAM in other slots.
2. Reinstall operating system.
3. Try different set of RAM.
4. Try another video card (no idea how I will get one).
5. Buy a new PSU
6. Buy another processor.
7. Buy a new motherboard.

The problem is that it occurs so rarely that when I change something I have to wait a day or so to see if it happens again.

If anyone has any idea what is going on, any suggestions, or insights, that would be very appreciated!

Here is my [dxdiag.txt](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hu6-crE3r6uhfy7U1yTHpLfnnUeKTPCzSEPwLJ3ZZnw/edit?usp=sharing) on Google docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with my experience . i have had more problems with my mother board burning out when gaming than i do with graphics cards . but if you do not have a decent graphics card then i would definitely upgrade . the noise u mention is coming from your mother board but doesn't necessarily mean it is the problem . i would go with the steps you listed in your troubleshoot list.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, quick question about your statement `noise u mention is coming from your mother board` Lamora has explicitly said the noise it coming from the speakers what would make you think it's the mobo?

Comment: Thank you, I have had the computer for about 4 years, I do not have much money to spend at the moment as I am paying for college now, I will definitely try to borrow a friend's video card to confirm between motherboard and graphics. Is their any chance it's the processor? It's such a rare freeze that I have been stumped and cannot replicate it because I am not doing anything stressing on my system when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my asus f5vl laptop.I disassembled it each ,removed each part cpu,ram,wifi card etc,cleaned those and assembled back and it worked.now when it happens I punch it softly and it works again.But in my case it was worse.I could not turn my pc on.
* Strangely it worked fine with just Opensolaris...