# Win10 Machine Freezing with Sound Oscillation

Tags: windows-10, audio, graphics-card, power-supply, freeze

***Update: MOBO was the Culprit. I RMA'd and the replacement did not work either (same issue) then I got a refund from NewEgg and purchased an MSI board. This MOBO has has no issues.***

I have these symptoms:

- Machine stops/freezes while watching videos or playing games (only
  time I notice)
- Reboots and clock is wrong once the machine reboots.
- Sound Oscillation or stuttering occurs while the freeze is happening.
- Machine reboots on its own, I do not need to touch the power button
  to make that happen.
- Mouse works while this is happening.

Hardware:

Radeon  RX 480 Graphics (Primary)
Radeon R7 360 (Secondary)
Windows 10 (64 bit)
16 GB Gskill Trident memory 
CPU AMD Ryzen 7 1800X Eight-Core Processor
650 W PSU
Gigabyte AB350-Gaming 3 Mobo
F6 Bios from GigaByte

Test I have done:

- I have ran temp checks and stability checks - 26C to 32C underload
- I have run MemTest86 bootable for 10 iterations - Clean
- I have ran DISM and SFC /scannow with no change
- Everything is on default settings
- Prime95 made my north and south bridge hit 100C but ran for 3 hours with no issues.
- I have changed PSU to a 680W I have lying around to no change
- I have changed RAM with a buddies, no change.
- I have not checked the issues or stressed under a different OS (todo)
- Replaced CMOS

Related questions:
[Computer freezes, makes buzzing noise on speakers](https://superuser.com/questions/668531/computer-freezes-makes-buzzing-noise-on-speakers?rq=1)
[Computer freezes with buzzing noise](https://superuser.com/questions/1034147/computer-freezes-with-buzzing-noise?rq=1)
[Computer freezes and sound stutters](https://superuser.com/questions/988566/computer-freezes-and-sound-stutters?rq=1)

None of these solved my problem but pointed me to some of my tests.
Any help is appreciated.

- It does look like this happens when both of my GPU's are under load at the same time, indicating a PSU issue. I have purchased an 850W one and am testing now.
- I am going to RMA my CPU first followed by the MOBO if that fails
- [Overclocker Topic](http://www.overclock.net/t/1625376/difference-between-f4-3600c16d-16gtzkw-and-f4-3600c16d-16gtz) proves its not my ram. Since the only difference is the color designation and not the actual chip or configuration.
- Checked memory compatibility in more depth. G.SKILL TridentZ RGB Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3200 (PC4 25600) Desktop Memory Model F4-3200C14D-16GTZR are the sticks I purchased, which is not on my Mobo's list. G.SKILL Flare X Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3200 (PC4 25600) AMD X370 / B350 Memory (Desktop Memory) Model F4-3200C14D-16GFX is the one that is closest and supported. I can see no difference beyond their model number. I have a ticket in with gigabyte and G.Skill.
- I have confirmed the BIOS I am using contains AGESA 1.0.0.4 update for the FMA3 bug. Disabling the virtual cores also does not resolve the issue. 850w Power supply has not resolved the issue.
- CPU was RMA'd makes no difference, will be returning MOBO next.

Comment: Anything in the System Event Logs?

Comment: Event logs only indicate that the machine shut down improperly. Also after about 1 hour my mouse starts to act erratically and jumpy. If I reboot the issue is resolved. I am beginning to think it is Mobo or cpu related but I have nothing to really point me to that.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the extra information. Comments are not the right place for this stuff.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you will edit to comply.

Comment: So I know this may not be much help, but ironically I had a Radeon R7 also, and had a lot of PC freezing issues. I was never able to pin point that as the problem until I got rid of the card. I originally thought it was the old computer I was using (An HP workstation) but then was fine after the card upgrade.

Comment: I would agree that could be the issue, except having tested both cards individually and still experienced the issue on both. Ill reverify once i get the mobo back.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams go ahead and post your solution (MoBo issue) as an answer and then mark it as such. This will let other Super Users find that solution if they are having similar issues. It also allows this question to go into the Answered pile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mobo was the issue. I replaced my Gigabyte AB350-Gaming 3 Mobo with an [MSI X370 GAMING PRO AM4 AMD X370](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813144017)